# Dynamic if statement based on user input

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, input, conditional-statements

I have a list with a couple of keys and values in it, each with their own keywords stored in it.

To only return specific items in the list, I use the following for loop with an if statement:

```
reduced_docs = []
for arg in reduced_docs:
    if 'amazon' in arg[1] and 'google' in arg[1]:
        print(arg[0])
```

The code above will return me all the items in the list that contain the words amazon and google. This works, but as you can see it's hardcoded now and I would something like this:

```
 reduced_docs = []
    keyword = input('enter your keywords:') keyword1 keyword2
     for arg in reduced_docs:
            if keyword in arg[1] and keyword in arg[1]:
                print(arg[0])
```

As you can see in the example code above, it's not hardcoded anymore, but what if I have 3 keywords or 4 or 5? What would I need to do to create a dynamic if statement that adds the `and`condition based on the length on the input? So far I can't get my head around this.

Comment: 2 possible approaches: 1.) First ask the user how many keywords they are gonna enter then have a loop asking n times for a keyword 2.) Keep asking the user in an infinite loop if they want to enter another keyword and break the loop if they decline.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What are `arg[0]` and `arg[1]`?

Comment: @PeterWood arg[0] is for example the id of a document and arg[1] is the content of the document. My structure is as follow List, within that List I have multiple tuples and arg[1] has a list with multiple values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`all(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` if all elements of `iterable` are true.

Using a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) together with that:

```
keywords = input('enter your keywords:').split()
for arg in reduced_docs:
    if all(keyword in arg[1] for keyword in keywords):
        print(arg[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does exactly what I want! Just one more question if you don't mind. What I would like to use OR instead. What would be the best approach?

Comment: @Solaiman for OR you would use [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) instead of [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all): `if any(keyword in arg[1] for keyword in keywords)`. `any` shortcircuits so is efficient. It will only check until it finds the first matching keyword.

Comment: @PeterWood thank you very much,that worked perfectly. Still learning new things everyday really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the user for comma separated keywords then use something like

```
 reduced_docs = []
    keywords = input('enter your keywords comma separated:')
     for arg in reduced_docs:
         to_print = []
         for keyword in keywords.split(","):
            to_print.append(keyword in arg[0])
         if all(to_print):
            print(arg[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this also worked. I would only split based on spaces instead of comma seperated values :)